# How is Ajax Destroy method for a nested resource is causing its parent resource to be destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have resources set up like this:

```
resources :scoreboards do
 resources :teams
end
```

On my `scoreboard#show` view page, I have a collection for the `team` model which generates a div for each team. Beside each team-div is a `Delete` button which routes to a method in the `teams_controller` to delete that team.

Here is a list of all the code associated with it:

**The Delete Button next to a team**

```
<div>team example</div> <%= link_to "Del", scoreboard_team_path(@scoreboard, team), remote: true, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

**The Teams_controller method for the button**

```
def destroy
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
     @team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
     @team.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to scoreboard_url(@scoreboard)}
         format.js
     end
   end
```

**The destroy.js.erb file**

```
$( "#team_<%=@team.id%>" ).hide();
```

Now the issue on hand is that whenever I click on a delete button really fast in quick succession(twice or more on one button), all the Ajax delete buttons stop working. This is most likely because the Scoreboard resource the teams were associated to has been deleted because I get the following error in the `Scoreboards_Controller`:

```
 NoMethodError in ScoreboardsController#show

undefined method `teams' for nil:NilClass

 def show
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.build  # new team form on the page
  @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new
  @schedule = @scoreboard.schedules.build
 end
```

Then when I check my list of Scoreboards, the @Scoreboard resource which the @team was associated to does not exist anymore. Why is that happening?

Edit: Checking the development logs has clarified what is happening.

So I click delete really fast and it destroys the Team associated with that delete button. Since I manage to click the delete button twice before the destroy.js.erb files processes(hides the deleted div), the Teams_Controller#destroy method is run again on the deleted team, however there is nothing to delete, therefore the Teams_Controller#destroy proceeds to redirect to @scoreboard. Now for some reason, the Scoreboards_Controller#destroy executes and deletes the @scoreboard and after that it attempts to redirect again and encounters a routing error because the scoreboard no longer exists.

Here is some of the log for clarification:

```
 Started DELETE "/scoreboards/45/teams/478" for 99.000.000.000 at 2015-12-12 03:54:09 +0000
Processing by TeamsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"scoreboard_id"=>"45", "id"=>"478"}
  [1m[36mScoreboard Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 45]]
  [1m[35mTeam Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."scoreboard_id" = ? AND "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["scoreboard_id", 45], ["id", 478]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ?  [["id", 478]]
  [1m[36m (10.6ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendered teams/destroy.js.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 28.1ms | ActiveRecord: 11.8ms)



   Started DELETE "/scoreboards/45/teams/478" for 99.000.000.000 at 2015-12-12 03:54:09 +0000
Processing by TeamsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"scoreboard_id"=>"45", "id"=>"478"}
  [1m[35mScoreboard Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 45]]
  [1m[36mTeam Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."scoreboard_id" = ? AND "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["scoreboard_id", 45], ["id", 478]]
Redirected to https://score-app-kpauls.c9.io/scoreboards/45
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Started DELETE "/scoreboards/45" for 99.000.000.000 at 2015-12-12 03:54:09 +0000
Processing by ScoreboardsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"45"}
  [1m[35mScoreboard Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 45]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 105]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 105]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "45"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mTeam Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."scoreboard_id" = ?[0m  [["scoreboard_id", 45]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ?  [["id", 479]]
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 480]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ?  [["id", 481]]
  [1m[36mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 482]]
  [1m[35mComment Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."scoreboard_id" = ?  [["scoreboard_id", 45]]
  [1m[36mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 45]]
  [1m[35m (14.1ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to https://score-app-kpauls.c9.io/scoreboards
Completed 302 Found in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)
```

After this the program encounters a routing error. I will continue to look into it but if anyone could help find the reason why scoreboards_controller#destroy is being called, it'd be really appreciated.

Update on the Problem:

So I have figured out the problem. I had these two methods in my `application_controller` file.

```
 rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  flash[:warning] = 'Resource not found.'
  redirect_back_or root_path 
 end

  def redirect_back_or(path)
   redirect_to request.referer || path
  end
```

Whenever, I would click on the delete button twice in quick succession, the destroy action would be rerouted to the scoreboard#show page and proceed to call the destroy method for that resource on the second click. This is because the @team which the destroy method was being called for had already been destroyed in the first click therefore requesting a redirect. I did get the flash messages after I refreshed the page to go the home page but dismissed them as relevant at first but they were key to the conclusion.

Comment: In your team and scoreboard models how did you set your depend: :destroy? This would be my first guess.

Comment: Maybe you have in team model belongs_to : scoreboard, dependent: :destroy (the destroy dependency should be in the scoreboard model instead)

Comment: In my Teams model I have only  `belongs_to :scoreboard` however in my scoreboard model, I have `has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy`. The code is executed correctly if I take my time, however, if i click on delete really fast in quick succession does it destroy the parent resource.

Comment: Anything in the logs that could show, what is actually triggering the bad delete post action?

Comment: Yep! The log clarifies why the @scoreboard is being deleted. I have updated the post with the log info however, I still can't figure out why Scoreboards_controller#destroy is being called.

Comment: I have made an suggestion in my answer. Also you can try to isolate the destroy path from the nested route and try to isolate the destroy process this will maybe help you to understand where is the trick. @rick answer is also an interesting suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The code infrastructure looks good, I would recommend looking at the associations and making sure you don't have `dependent: :destroy` on `team belongs_to :scoreboard`

--

In regards the problem of multiple "delete" button clicking, the problem looks like you're getting a redirect to the parent resource. I don't have any reason why this would be the case, except that perhaps Rails has an inbuilt set of functionality to load "parent" routes if the child fails.

The way I would tackle the fix is to use conditions:

```
def destroy
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
     @team = @scoreboard.teams.find params[:id]
     if @team.destroy
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to scoreboard_url(@scoreboard)} #-> could this be the reason for the redirect?????
         format.js
       end
     else
         redirect_to scoreboard_teams_path(@scoreboard), notice: "Team Already Deleted"
     end
end
```

I'd also look at conditioning the `@team` -- `if @team && @team.destroy` - I can refactor if you wanted more information.

Doing this will give you a definite flow which can handle exceptions. I think the problem is that when you click the delete button (and the record no longer exists), Rails is unable to handle the exception.

The inbuilt way that Rails comes back with errors is to redirect to the `object_path(@object)`, and show the errors (like you've got in your `format.html`).

Therefore, I would *guess* that Rails is trying to take you back to `@scoreboard` (`scoreboard_path(@scoreboard)`), and since you have `method: :delete`, it's running the `destroy` method for that controller.

To fix it, you'd need to use the conditions above to let Rails know what to do in case of problems.

Comment: Reading your answer give me an idea. The line  team = scoreboard.teams.find params[:id] (I remove the @ for the comment) means that it's a scoreboard object that is return. So the destroy method is trigger on this one no? This can explain the destroy call on the scoreboard object.

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions made by you guys and it still breaks the ajax for the other delete buttons(most likely because the @scoreboard is still being deleted). I had a similar problem earlier where form submits would occur twice or more if I clicked on the submit button really fast. Therefore, I have added a `:data => {:disable_with => "..."}`(this solved the multple submit problem) inside the ruby code for the delete link(stopping multiple succesive controller requests). I will keep trying to refactor for exceptions but thank you guys for your help! I will upvote.

Comment: Updated original post. There was a problem outside of the teams controller.

Answer (score 1):

In your teams_controller in the destroy action, I suggest you change this line:

```
@team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
```

for

```
@team = Team.find(params[:id])
```